# Errors on LibGDX tutorial

Tags: libgdx

I get the following errors on the LibGDX tutorial ["Simple App"](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp#The_Full_Source)

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gdx64 in
>   java.library.path     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:118)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglNativesLoader.load(LwjglNativesLoader.java:41)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.(LwjglApplication.java:52)
>     at com.badlogic.drop.DesktopGame.main(DesktopGame.java:7)

I copied and pasted the final code onto the project, but I don't know why it wont run.

Whats the problem?  Is it the project set-up?

Comment: Look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLx_72qxK_0&feature=player_embedded#!

Comment: I'm asking what is the problem.  Not how to set it up.

Comment: Try posting on the libGDX forums, you get generally better responses than gamedev.se

Comment: In the video it shows linking to gdx natives. It looks like the gdx64 natives can't be found. Did you include them? http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/libs/

Comment: I have gdx-backened-lwjgl-natives, gdx-backened-lwjgl, gdx-natives, and gdx.

Comment: Well, (obviously) from your error, GdxNativesLoader can't find gdx64.dll. I see you're targeting lwjgl but in my Android project, I have a libs directory with the arm.so's. You might have to have gdx.64.dll in your lwjgl project under the directory structure like the link above.

Comment: Actually, if you look at GdxNativesLoader, gdx64 is a resource. http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/GdxNativesLoader.java

Comment: It sounds like the JVM might be hosed?

Comment: I just added the libGDX 0.9.3 and it worked, but i got an error on the sound :(  "Error creating sound com.badlogic.gdx.backends.openal.Wav$Sound for file: drop.wav"  its funny cause now if someone puts the 1st part of this comment, that person would get the answer check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the libraries of libGdx.